# execvp() system call not executing

Tags: c

```
char *args[41];
char str[41], teststr[41];
const char delimiter[2]=" ";
memcpy(teststr, str, sizeof(str));
args[i]=strtok(teststr, delimiter);
while(args[i]!=NULL)
{
    printf("args[%d]=%s\n", i, args[i]);
    i++;
    args[i]=strtok(NULL, delimiter);
}
```

This is a code I used to intialize args[].

Below code is to execute execvp() system call.

```
pid=fork();
if(pid==0)
{
    execvp(args[0], args);
}
```

When I run the code, execvp runs few commands. Such as when I try to execute 'ls' command, it will work but when I try to run 'date' command or 'cd' command, it does not work. And when I try to execute 'cat' command, prompt does not show anything and at the same time it does not come out of it.

Comment: `cd` is never going to work with `exec` and friends, since this command is built into the shell as a result of a process not being able to change the working directory of its parent process. This may be the case with `date` also, but `cat` ought to work OK. And obviously, in the code you actually show, `str` is never actually populated or initialized, and so this shouldn't be working at all. You also should be using `strcpy()` to populate `args` (which will mean changing the definition of `args` to allocate memory), and not storing pointers to a string which `strtok()` is going to modify.

Comment: OK but the thing is, in case of cat supose I give command myshell>cat shell.c where myshell is a shell which I am creating. When I run this command, it enters child process but never comes out of it and also no output is displayed.

Comment: `>` is for shell redirection, if you're trying to pass that as a command line argument it's clearly not going to work.

Comment: > is a part of myshell> which I am printing using printf statement

Comment: Add a `main()` function and the relevant `#include`s to the code you've posted to create a minimal compilable working example, and we'll be able to see what's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have issues with how you're getting your arguments, although since you don't show your input, it's hard to tell. `strtok()` modifies the string you pass to it, so storing pointers to that string you're modifying looks like trouble.

This will do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_LEN 1024
#define MAX_ARGS 100

int main(void) {
    char command[MAX_BUFFER_LEN];

    printf("myshell> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(command, MAX_BUFFER_LEN, stdin); 
    command[strlen(command) - 1] = '\0';

    char * args[MAX_ARGS];
    char * temparg;
    int i = 0;

    temparg = strtok(command, " ");
    while ( temparg ) {
        args[i] = strdup(temparg);
        ++i;
        temparg = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    i = 0;
    while ( args[i] != NULL ) {
        printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i + 1, args[i]);
        ++i;
    }

    pid_t my_pid = fork();
    if ( my_pid == 0 ) {
        execvp(args[0], args);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./exectest
myshell> cat exectest.c
Argument 1: cat
Argument 2: exectest.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_LEN 1024
#define MAX_ARGS 100

int main(void) {
    char command[MAX_BUFFER_LEN];

    printf("myshell> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(command, MAX_BUFFER_LEN, stdin); 
    command[strlen(command) - 1] = '\0';

    char * args[MAX_ARGS];
    char * temparg;
    int i = 0;

    temparg = strtok(command, " ");
    while ( temparg ) {
        args[i] = strdup(temparg);
        ++i;
        temparg = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    i = 0;
    while ( args[i] != NULL ) {
        printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i + 1, args[i]);
        ++i;
    }

    pid_t my_pid = fork();
    if ( my_pid == 0 ) {
        execvp(args[0], args);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$
```

Some error-checking omitted for brevity.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This solution works, now I know that why my code wasn't working. That was because my str was not NULL terminated